# Comando SQL duplica mis datos

Tags: sql, mysqli

Tengo un una base de datos de **PROSPECTOS** *y toda su información*, relacionado a un catálogo de **MARCAS** (LG, SAMSUNG) y **EQUIPOS** (ESTUFA, LAVADORA) y los prospectos se vuelven **SERVICIOS** después de algunos procesos, entonces vamos a asignar servicios por **EMPLEADO**, si yo hago el siguiente comando SQL logro obtener el total de 25 **SERVICIOS** actuales **ASIGNADOS** al **EMPLEADO #2**:

```
select * from servicios where id_empleado = 2
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando hago mi JOIN para obtener toda la relación de **MARCA, EQUIPO, PROSPECTO, SERVICIO y EMPLEADO** me duplica los resultados, no entiendo porque, yo hice este comando SQL:

```
SELECT p.nombre_completo, p.direccion, p.telefono, p.correo, e.nombre, m.nombre_marca, p.fecha_de_visita, p.hora_de_visita, p.diagnostico, s.id_servicio FROM prospectos p, marca m, equipo e, servicios s, empleado em WHERE p.id_prospecto = s.id_prospecto and p.id_marca = m.id_marca and p.id_equipo = e.id_equipo and s.id_empleado = 2
```

En la imagen verán como duplica los resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto imágenes de las tablas y sus relaciones:

SERVICIOS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PROSPECTO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EQUIPO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MARCA:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EMPLEADO:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Todo depende de las relaciones de tus tablas. Las filas no están repetidas, hay alguna columna con un valor distinto. También debes saber que esa sintaxis es obsoleta desde hace más de 20 años.

Comment: Gracias por la observación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno primeramente veo que no usitlizas `empleado em` en ningun momento, ahora bien te recomendaria que utilices `JOIN` ya sea `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, etc. Según necesites.
Tendria que ver la estructura de tus tablas para poder ayudarte mejor pero por el momento según analizo tu código SQL podrias intentar con lo siguiente:

```
SELECT p.nombre_completo, p.direccion, p.telefono, p.correo, e.nombre, m.nombre_marca, p.fecha_de_visita, p.hora_de_visita, p.diagnostico, s.id_servicio 
FROM servicios s
INNER JOIN prospectos p ON p.id_prospecto = s.id_prospecto
INNER JOIN marca m ON p.id_marca = m.id_marca
INNER JOIN equipo e ON p.id_equipo = e.id_equipo
WHERE s.id_empleado = 2
```

Comment: Ya agregue mis tablas, ahi se puede ya ver la relación que tengo en todas ellas

Comment: ok ahora le hecho un vistazo

Comment: ¿Una duda, porque @Luis Cazares dice que esa sintaxis es obsoleta?

Comment: Imagino por el hecho de poner todas tus tablas en un `FROM` y luego comparar sus llaves en un `WHERE` en lugar de utilizar el `INNER` respectivamente

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda